# gtkmm drawing area on raspberry pi armhf not showing

Tags: raspberry-pi, gtkmm, gtkmm3, drawingarea, armhf

There are some examples for programming with gtkmm 3.0, which can be found here:
[Gtk::DrawingArea example from upmf-grenoble](http://transit.iut2.upmf-grenoble.fr/doc/gtkmm-3.0/tutorial/html/sec-cairo-drawing-lines.html)

When I compile this example on my pc (amd64), I get the expected Gtk::DrawingArea.

When I compile this exact same example on my raspberry pi 3B (armhf), there are no errors or warnings and I get an executable file, just like on my pc. When I execute it, I get an opening window, but the Gtk::DrawingArea is not shown.

Other examples work fine. If I create an example program with a Gtk::DrawingArea and Gtk::Buttons, the program runs and the Gtk::Buttons work, but the Gtk::DrawingArea is not shown. No errors!

Do I need a special library on the raspberry? But should this not have thrown an error at compile time, if something is missing? Can this be a monitor issue? Is there a log file, helping me find out, what is wrong?

Thanks for any hint.

EDIT:
The raspberry pi 3B has a 64-bit processor. I had installed the official 32-bit OS for it. With this 32-bit OS, I do not get anything to see from the Gtk::DrawingArea. With the official 64-bit OS, the Gtk::DrawingArea works fine.

I do not know, what goes wrong with the official 32-bit install. The raspberry pi should also be capable of the 32-bit OS. Anyhow... if you switch to 64-bit, I recommend doing so, when using a Gtk::DrawingArea.